# "Handling of Task 1" or "Handling Task 1"

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, possessives, ellipses

I am working on my thesis and included is a subsection in which I describe how a part of a class of my program handles the task I have been assigned for the thesis.

To give you an idea of what the structure of the table of contents looks like:

> 4.2 IntegrityChecker class
>
> 4.2.1 Handling **of** Task 1
>
> 4.2.2 Handling **of** Task 2
>
> [... etc]

Someone told me the "of" in the subsection title could possibly be redundant.

Is this true? Would "Handling Task 1" be better? Or possibly "The handling of Task 1"?

Comment: 'Handling' sounds a little informal to my ears. 'Implementation' is more formal.

Comment: Just because you ***can*** get rid of a word, it doesn't mean that you should. I think it's better with the *of*.

Comment: @PeterShor Alternatively, the OP could improve the ToC by removing *Handling of* altogether, depending on the actual wording of each *Task n*.

Comment: Task 1 Handler, Task 2 Handler?

Answer (score 2):

The 'of' reduces the chance of confusion, as it's clear this means that it is how to handle task 1, whereas the **handling task 1** could mean it's a task about handling (such as a manual labour task).